Можно ли пояснительные конструкции оформлять таким образом: в начале – тире, в конце – запятая?
Титов замок – величественный памятник архитектуры XVI века, находится в небольшом населенном пункте.

Если контекста нет и действительно это пояснительная (скорее дополнительная) конструкция, то должен ставиться парный знак (при условии что другие знаки в данном предложении не нужны):
Титов замок – величественный памятник архитектуры XVI века – находится в небольшом населенном пункте.
Если задумывался другой смысл – и как раз при исходной пунктуации он и вырисовывается, – то вместо запятой нужна точка и неперестройка следующего текста:
Титов замок – величественный памятник архитектуры XVI века. Находится он в небольшом населенном пункте.
Дополнение после комментариев
Полное предложение из журнала выглядит так:
Титов замок – величественный памятник архитектуры XVI века, находится в небольшом населенном пункте Тит на живописном берегу Волги среди многовековых дубов и кленов.
С точки зрения грамматики такое возможно: запятой разделены части бессоюзного сложного предложения, пропуск подлежащего допустим. Но второе предложение настолько осложнено тремя неоднородными распространёнными обстоятельствами, а словосочетание "населенный пункт" никак не вписывается в "величественную, живописную, многовековую" атмосферу (нужно было заменить на человеческое место), что включать эту часть в общее сообщение совсем не хочется.
Вывод: добавить подлежащее, подчистить стилистику – и такая пунктуация сойдёт.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

@Людмила Петрикова Рекомендую для прочтения. Узнаете, сколькими СПОСОБАМИ можно оформить ваше предложение. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/480687/Загадки-одного-и-двух-тире-при-обособлении-приложения
