Загадки одного и двух тире при обособлении приложения
Рассмотрим предложение:
Титов замок(?) величественный памятник архитектуры XVI века(?) находится в небольшом населенном пункте.

Правила позволяют использовать запятые, одно тире или два тире: Розенталь, пункты 5 и 10.

Сколько ВАРИАНТОВ оформления с разными знаками возможно для этого предложения? От чего зависит выбор?


Примечания
(1) Приложение и определяемое существительное можно менять местами.
(2) Предложение из недавней темы Оно вызвало некоторое недоумение с точки зрения стиля (величественный замок и населенный пункт). Но при решении это не учитываем, а разбираем грамматику и пунктуацию.


Две запятые: уточнение при небольшой распространенности приложения; две паузы. Пункт 5, приложение, стоящее после имени собственного

Титов замок, архитектурный памятник XVI века, находится в небольшом населенном пункте N.

Два тире: приложение, носящее характер пояснения;  вставочная интонация; две увеличенные паузы. Пункт 10 (3)

Титов замок — величественный памятник архитектуры XVI века — находится в небольшом населенном пункте N.

Одно тире: актуализация оборота с дополнительным значением причины, значение "будучи". Пункт 5 и 10 (примечание 3)

Величественный памятник архитектуры XVI века — Титов замок вызывает постоянный интерес уникальностью многих решений, а также своим расположением на живописном берегу реки среди многовековых дубов и кленов.

Тире-дефис (условное название), если приложение более конкретно, чем определяемое слово. Произношение без паузы. Пункт 10 (примечание 2)

Один из интереснейших памятников архитектуры — Титов замок // находится в небольшом населенном пункте.

Одна запятая: информационное сообщение (к примеру, в кратком путеводителе) в виде бессоюзного сложного предложения, вторая часть распространяет первую часть; тире между подлежащими сказуемым, пропущенное подлежащее во второй части

Титов замок  — величественный памятник архитектуры XVI века, (он) находится в небольшом населенном пункте N.
Этот вариант используется редко
ВЫВОД
В приведенном предложении для обособления приложения следует использовать два тире (лучший вариант, пояснительное значение) или две запятые (уточнение). Одно тире применяется в особых случаях.

А каким правилом объяснятся запятая и тире?

Это пункт 5? Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым ( И.п. - И.п.), а запятая в БСП, второе предложение распространяет первое, продолжает его тему.

БСП? Не думаю. Без подлежащего предложение безупречно, к тому же ведь и так ясно, что глагол "находится" к чему относится.

По семантике ясно, а по грамматике нет. Если бы это было односоставное предложение 1-ое и 2-ое лицо, то да, а это 3-е лицо. И предложение отнюдь не безупречно, а вызывает много вопросов. Здесь надо было использовать или две запятые, или два тире, чего проще, но договориться с автором вопроса удалось не сразу.

Согласен! Или две запятые, или два тире.

Спасибо, Серж! Я внесла  этот вывод в ответ.  Варианты с одним тире возможны при изменении структуры предложения.

Да, при изменении структуры возможно одно тире. Одно тире было бы возможно, если бы этого требовало структура предложения.

Я говорю пр одно тире, потому что правомерен вопрос: можно ли здесь использовать одно тире. В конкретном предложении без перестройки нельзя, но в  данной теме можно. Я смотрю, как объясняют тему на других ресурсах, и там одно тире трактуют как нечто очень специфичное (для делового стиля, например). Но как мы видим, в данном тексте эту форму можно применить,  Думаю, то такое сравнение способов оформления будет полезно и нам, и нашим читателям.

Sharon, возможно, я некорректно выразился. Да, при изменении структуры возможно одно тире. Я не спорю. Я говорил о другом. Без изменения структуры возможно было поставить одно тире, если бы это требовало структура предложения.
